# keyword with primary key to generate unique id

Tags: mysql

What keyword can I use with the primary key to generate a unique id for each new row in a table?

UNIQUE_ID 
AUTO_INCREMENT
INCREMENT_ID
AUTO_INCREMENT_ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) is the best(and possibly only) choice for that.